# No lazy/delayed loading on UICollectionView inside an UITableViewCell

Tags: ios6, uitableview, lazy-loading, uicollectionview

I have a UITableViewCell with an UICollectionView inside it. My custom UITableViewCell is responsible for the datasource and methods for the UICollectionView. All works perfectly except when I add some logging to the cellForItemAtIndexPath I see that all UICollectionViewCells will be loaded at once. So there goes my lazy/delayed loading when scrolling down.

Here is my logging in the custom UITableViewCell

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView                cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Loading cell: %i", indexPath.row);
}
```

The tableViewCell height is automaticaly calculated based on the items the UICollectioNView needs to handle. So  in the tableview method of my ViewController:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //return dynamically the height based on the items to show in the collectionview.
}
```

So I guess this is my problem and reason why it doesn't do lazy loading. Is there an easy fix for this ? Or is this the way:

[image: Putting a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell]

Source: http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell

By this the lazy loading will only be handled by the UITableView and not the UICollectionView.

Here is the full code of my custom UITableViewCell, but as you will see this is really nothing special.

```
@implementation PeopleJoinedThisPlaceCell

@synthesize people = _people;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    collectionView.delegate = self;
    collectionView.dataSource = self;
    collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

- (void)setPeople:(NSArray *)people
{
    _people = people;
    [collectionView reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - CollectionViewController delegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    if(_people == NULL) return 0;
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(_people == NULL) return 0;
    return _people.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView_ cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Loading cell: %i", indexPath.row);
    ImageCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"People" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *userPlace = [_people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFUser *user = [userPlace objectForKey:UserClassName];
    [cell.BackgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-big-bg"]];
    [cell.ImageLoader startAnimating];
    [[UserPhotos sharedInstance] getCachedSmallPhotoForUser:user withBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        [cell.ImageView setImage:image];
        [cell.ImageLoader stopAnimating];
    }];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView_ didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PFObject *userPlace = [_people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [_delegate gotoUserProfile:userPlace];
}

@end
```

Comment: How many cells total are you loading? It's possible that iOS is preloading collection view cells and that amount just happens to overflow all of them. For example, if you have 20 cells but only 10 are visible at once, that's probably fine.

Comment: I added some data and there are now total 169 UICollectionViewCells loaded directly.

Comment: Question remains why this wont work but I fixed it now by creating multiple UITableViewCells with each one UICollectionView containing max 3 items for each row. By this the UITableView delay loads the rows when scrolling done and it looks the same (like a large UICollectionView). So I did it like the image in the question.